# oracle grant to public after create any table

Tags: oracle

I granted `CREATE ANY TABLE` privilege to allow another user to create tables for my user. Ok. That worked. I want to allow this same user, after they created the table, to grant select privilege to public. But the Oracle says: insufficient privileges.

How can I grant select privileges to a table I have just created?

Comment: Why does the other account need to create tables in your schema in the first place?

Comment: Be careful when you are granting select on a table to public. Make sure that's what you really want to do. It is much safer to create a group, grant select on a table to that group and then you can add whatever users to that group. Much safer and easier to manager and much better practice